# Converting linux driver to android usb api ch341

Tags: android, c, linux-device-driver

Well,

I trying to convert a ch341 linux driver to android usb api. I'm very knew to those drivers things and may I should apologize you for those silly questions below.

```
CH341, know as usb serial cable hl-340 or even 0x1a86/0x7523, vid/pid.
```

The driver I found is not a libusb, it's a kernel driver (which I think more difficult to read).
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c

**Is possible to convert a kernel driver to Google USB API?**

I mean, all the stuff needed by a kernel driver can be accomplished, or at least for this specific driver?

I could recode the open, configure, controlIn and out. I do not know if it's working, but I didn't get error messages yet.

`controlIn` code part:

```
private int controlIn(int request, int value, int index, byte[] buffer, int bufsize)
{
    int r;

    r = mConnection.controlTransfer(UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN | 0x40, request, value, index,
            buffer, bufsize, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    return r;
}
```

The code below, which functions are called to read and write to the device?
Or, what is the procedure to read and write the data of my usb device?

```
static struct usb_serial_driver ch341_device = {
    .driver = {
        .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
        .name   = "ch341-uart",
    },
    .id_table          = id_table,
    .num_ports         = 1,
    .open              = ch341_open,
    .dtr_rts       = ch341_dtr_rts,
    .carrier_raised    = ch341_carrier_raised,
    .close             = ch341_close,
    .set_termios       = ch341_set_termios,
    .break_ctl         = ch341_break_ctl,
    .tiocmget          = ch341_tiocmget,
    .tiocmset          = ch341_tiocmset,
    .tiocmiwait        = usb_serial_generic_tiocmiwait,
    .read_int_callback = ch341_read_int_callback,
    .port_probe        = ch341_port_probe,
    .port_remove       = ch341_port_remove,
    .reset_resume      = ch341_reset_resume,
};
```

Thanks

Comment: In theory you could eventually adapt a kernel driver (beware of licensing implications though!) but in practice it may be better to use the kernel driver as a hint for what type of device, or at the extreme, what necessary operations you are dealing with.  USB serial cables come in a handful of standard schemes widely duplicated - chances are learning what the kernel driver does could inform adapting some other Android USB API solution for a different cable.  Typically USB serial is not very complicated.

Comment: Also, you might consider comparing this kernel driver to the kernel driver for a cable for which you can find Android example code - if there is not a large stylistic difference between the two kernel drivers, what's different in on form would need to be similarly different in the other.